# undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass in ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

`c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,nil,nil,nil]
c.map{ |i| p i if i > 10 }`

NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

How to avoid 'nil' values during comparison?

Comment: You cant do `>` on `nil` in ruby

Comment: if there is any solution do avoid that?

Comment: `nil.to_i` will convert it to 0

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
c.map { |i| p i if i.to_i > 10 }
```

The error is telling you that you can't compare `nil`. Telling ruby to explicitly convert `i` to an integer will convert `nil` values to `0`.

```
> 0.to_i
 => 0
> 1.to_i
 => 1
> nil.to_i
 => 0
```

Note that here none of the values in your array validate the condition `i > 10`. Therefor it will return an array of `nil` values.

```
> c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,nil,nil,nil]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, nil, nil, nil]
> c.map { |i| i if i.to_i > 10 }
 => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]

> c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11,nil,nil]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, nil, nil]
> c.map { |i| i if i.to_i > 10 }
 => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 11, nil, nil]
```

You can use the [compact](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) method to clean the result:

```
> _.compact
 => [11]
```

Event better using [select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
> c.select { |i| i.to_i > 10 }
 => [11]
```

Comment: It returns the nil for all values.

Comment: That's because none of the values in your array validate the condition `i > 10`

Comment: if c = ['2014-03-01 12-00-45 ","2014-03-17 22-05-07",nil,nil]

Comment: Those are dates not integers, different story.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `compact` to remove the nil values before applying `map` to it:

```
c.compact.map { |i| p i if i > 10 }
```